# How to graph “before and after” measures using ggplot with connecting lines?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph, data-visualization

I’m new to R I want to create a ”before-and-after” scatterplot with connecting lines to illustrate the different power outputs before and after a training intervention.

I want something like the graph in the picture.

Example

```
Sample Data
X <- c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1) # 0=before, 1=after
y <- c(1001,1030,900,950,1040,1020,1010,1000) #Power output
Group <- c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1) # 0=Control 1=Experimental
id <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4) # id = per individual
df <- data.frame(x,y,Group,id)
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1) # 0=before, 1=after
y <- c(1001,1030,900,950,1040,1020,1010,1000) #Power output
Group <- c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1) # 0=Control 1=Experimental
id <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4) # id = per individual
df <- dplyr::bind_cols(
  x = x,
  y = y,
  Group = as.factor(Group),
  id = as.factor(id)
)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) +
  aes(x,y, color = Group, shape = Group, group = id)+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()
```

Comment: My dataset is already named ds how should I modify the script to use my ds instead of using dplyr:bind_cols?                                                                                                          df <- dplyr::bind_cols(
  x = x,
  y = y,
  Group = as.factor(Group),
  id = as.factor(id)
)

Comment: hi, either way is fine, your grouping variable `Group` and `id` need to be factors, not numeric. that is the important part